# SFML platformer using tile map in c++

Tags: c++, sfml

Hi i have a class for my mapping and it is drawing to the screen however its only drawing vertically down the left side of the window. i can figure out where I have gone wrong. any help would be much appreciated. Pretty sure its something to do with my for loop in the draw function.

```
void Map::Initialise(const char *filename)
{
     std::ifstream openfile(filename);
     std::string line;
     std::vector <int>  tempvector;
    while(!openfile.eof())
    {
        std::getline(openfile, line);

        for(int i =0; i < line.length(); i++)
        {
            if(line[i] != ' ') // if the value is not a space
            {
                char value[1] = {line[i]}; // store the character into the line variable
                tempvector.push_back(atoi(value)); // then push back the value stored in value into the temp vector
            }
            mapVector.push_back(tempvector); // push back the value of the temp vector into the map vector
            tempvector.clear(); // clear the temp vector readt for the next value
        }
    }
}


void Map::DrawMap(sf::RenderWindow &Window)
{
    sf::Shape rect = sf::Shape::Rectangle(0, 0, BLOCKSIZE, BLOCKSIZE, sf::Color(255, 255, 255, 255));
    sf::Color rectCol;
    sf::Sprite sprite;
    for(int i = 0; i < mapVector.size(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < mapVector[i].size(); j++)
        {
            if(mapVector[i][j] == 0)

               rectCol = sf::Color(44, 117, 255);

            else if (mapVector[i][j] == 1)

                rectCol = sf::Color(255, 100, 17);

            rect.SetPosition(j * BLOCKSIZE, i * BLOCKSIZE);
            rect.SetColor(rectCol);
            Window.Draw(rect);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make your extraction the condition of the `while` loop:

```
while(std::getline(openfile, line))
{
  // ...
}
```

Using `openfile.eof()` is a very bad idea; just because you haven't hit the end of the file yet, doesn't mean the next extraction is going to succeed. You just keep going with no idea if you actually have a valid `line` or not.

Secondly, this isn't going to work correctly:

```
char value[1] = {line[i]}; // store the character into the line variable
tempvector.push_back(atoi(value));
```

I can see why you used a `char[1]` - you wanted it to be converted to a pointer because `atoi` takes a `const char*`. However, `atoi` also expects the array it's pointing at to be null terminated. Your's isn't. It's just a single `char`.

There's a much nicer way to convert from a `char` which is a numerical digit to the integer it represents. The values of all numeric digit characters are guaranteed to be consecutive:

```
char value = line[i];
tempvector.push_back(value - '0');
```

Now, here's the real problem. Your pushing your `tempvector` into the `mapVector` after reading only a single character. You need to move it outside of the `for` loop for the line:

```
while(std::getline(openfile, line))
{
    for(int i =0; i < line.length(); i++)
    {
        // ...
    }

    // Moved here
    mapVector.push_back(tempvector); // push back the value of the temp vector into the map vector
    tempvector.clear(); // clear the temp vector readt for the next value
}
```

Comment: wow thanks for your feedback. It would seem I have made many mistakes. ill get right onto sorting it out

Comment: @TomFlan The last one is causing you the problem with it only drawing on the left side of the map. :)

Comment: made the changes however now its not drawing at all.

Comment: Im unsure how that would solve the problem of it drawing on the left side because thats the load function.

Comment: @TomFlan That's strange. Can you post your updated code on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and link it here?

Comment: @TomFlan It affects it because each of the `tempvector`s will only ever have one element in it. So they'll only ever draw in the first column.